# How to compute a/b mod P, P is a prime number?

Tags: java, number-theory, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

I have been searching an answer for this question on various sites. I can understand all the basic rules of modular arithmetic until this bad guy comes in. Recently I have been suggested this page for simple understanding that question:http://theoryofprogramming.com/2014/12/24/modular-arithmetic-properties/

I have understood how to compute a/b mod P and then I tried to code for the same (a*b^P-2 mod P).
It's suggested that b^P-2 mod P takes only O(log P) time if we use the Binary Exponentiation method.

```
    public static long BinaryExp(long base,long power) {
    long prime = (long)Math.pow(10, 9) + 7;
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (power == 1) {
        return Math.floorMod(base, prime);
    }
    else {
        long temp = BinaryExp(base, power/2);
        temp = Math.floorMod(Math.floorMod(temp,prime)*Math.floorMod(temp,prime), prime);
        if ((power%2)== 0) {
            return Math.floorMod(temp, prime);
        }
        else return Math.floorMod(temp*Math.floorMod(base, prime),prime);
    }   
}
```

This is my function for binary exponentiation. for input (30, 8) output is 99995408. If I change all longs to ints for the same input (30,8) output is 970003726. I can't figure why it's changing as there is no integer overflow (at least visibly). And the correct answer is 99995408 as per the windows calculator. Please help, I really want to move forward. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a compiler issue in your code: `Math.floorMod(, prime)`

Comment: Why do you believe that `temp*Math.floorMod(base, prime)` will not overflow an `int`? Since `base % prime` can be as large as `1_000_000_006`, any `temp` value of 3 or greater can cause `int` overflow.

Comment: @VinceEmigh thanks for pointing out, I have edited that part locally but forgot edit it here. Edited it now.

Comment: @Andreas  yes, it totally makes sense. It means that even changing  `temp*Math.floorMod(base, prime)` to `Math.floorMod(temp,prime)*Math.floorMod(base,prime)` doesn't help much. Can I conclude that it is mandatory to use `long` ( at least for `temp` ) ?